# :EXPORT from Package in Common Lisp

Tags: package, export, common-lisp

I have defined a package like the following:

```
(defpackage :thehilariouspackageofamirteymuri
  (:nicknames ampack amir teymuri)
  (:use common-lisp)
  (:export say-hi-to))
(in-package :amir)

(defun say-hi ()
  "Docstring"
  "Hello")

(defun say-hi-to (who)
  (concatenate 'string (say-hi) " " who " from " (package-name *package*) "!"))
```

Now changing to the package also the #'say-hi is accessible:

```
(in-package :amir)
(say-hi) ; -> "Hello"
(say-hi-to "World") ; -> "Hello World from THEHILARIOUSPACKAGEOFAMIRTEYMURI!"
```

Isn't the export keyword telling to make things external for the package? Why is the non-external #'say-hi also exported?

Comment: What makes you think that `say-hi` is exported?

Comment: Because changing to the created package i call it.

Comment: Sure, you are changing to the package. But what has that to do with exporting? What do you think? Ask yourself what the effect of 'exporting' actually does...

Comment: Can you access it from the `cl-user` package ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you are using again `(in-package :amir)` the following forms are evaluated in that package, so that you can use all the function defined in it. To check which definitions are exported, you should switch to a different package.

Let’s try the standard package `CL-USER`:

```
AMIR> (in-package :cl-user)
#<Package "COMMON-LISP-USER">
CL-USER> (say-hi)
Undefined function SAY-HI called with arguments ("world")  ; as expected, but...
CL-USER> (say-hi-to "world")
Undefined function SAY-HI-TO called with arguments ("world") ; ops!!
CL-USER> (amir:say-hi-to "world)
"Hello world from COMMON-LISP-USER!"
CL-USER> (amir:say-hi)
Reader error: No external symbol named "SAY-HI" in package #<Package "THEHILARIOUSPACKAGEOFAMIRTEYMURI"> .
```

The reason is that exporting a symbol does not mean that we can use it without qualiyfing its package. As you can see, however, only symbols exported from a packgage can be used with “:”. If you want to use the symbol without the package name as prefix, you must import it before.

So, let’s start again.

```
CL-USER> (defpackage :another-package (:use :amir))
#<Package "ANOTHER-PACKAGE">
CL-USER> (in-package :another-package)
#<Package "ANOTHER-PACKAGE">
ANOTHER-PACKAGE> (say-hi-to "world")
"Hello world from ANOTHER-PACKAGE!"
ANOTHER-PACKAGE> (say-hi)
Undefined function SAY-HI called with arguments ()
```

Inside `ANOTHER-PACKAGE` you can now use the exported symbol without qualifications.

In general, exporting and importing symbols in packages in Common Lisp is not so intuitive, and a good description of all the intricacies of packages can be found at the link cited in the other answer.

Answer (score 1):

Check the difference without changing the current package. You will find more information e.g. [here](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/programming-in-the-large-packages-and-symbols.html)